# Throw exception indicating variable name upon InvalidOperationException upon Nullable->Value

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a large set of Nullable<> variables as input to a somewhat complex algorithm, some of which shouldn't be null in certain contexts. At the moment, I'm relying on the InvalidOperationException thrown upon Nullable<>.Value when I hit that wall. The client app of my algo thereby knows by that exception that something is missing, but doesn't know what.

I'm looking for a way to catch that exception and get back to the name of the variable that caused it (those variables have human-readable names), so my client app can get informed of it. I'm thinking Reflection is the only way, but where do I start ?

Comment: `Nullable<>` doesn't seem a valid C code. Please use correct tag(s).

Comment: I'm fairly sure you meant to tag this [c#], not [c].  C doesn't have any of the things you're talking about - no Nullable, no InvalidOperationException, no generic types, no exceptions, no reflection...

Comment: Is it practical to check all of the contextual shouldn't-be-null constraints explicitly, upon entry to this complex algorithm?  That allows you to write coherent error messages for each case *and* it means you can unbox everything up front, for better efficiency.

Comment: this has been retagged as C#

Comment: @zwol right on the point, the only reason to do this is precisely because it is impractical to check case by case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that Reflection will indeed work well with handling this particular scenario, but I'm somewhat shocked that conditional based checking is impractical? You must not have control over this, but please understand that exception handling is very intensive performance wise, and conditional checks would emit better results. Regardless you can obtain the public properties of the object in question, and inspect the values given information about the type. Consider the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int? FirstInteger { get; set; }
    public int? SecondInteger { get; set; }
}

public class AwesomeAlgorithm
{
    public static void DoSomething(MyClass c)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Something is missing.");
        }
        catch(InvalidOperationException)
        {
            foreach(PropertyInfo t in c.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if(t.GetValue(c) == null)
                {
                    //Your code would go here. Console.Writeline as example.
                    Console.WriteLine("Property {0} appears to be null.", t.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the values are indeed null the conditional operation will run... funny part is we still are using a conditional operator. I personally don't care for this approach, but sometimes we don't have the control we need over this type of thing.

Another thing that might be more reasonable would be to supply default values for your method as long as it doesn't incorrectly manipulate your calculations:

```
public void MyMethod(int? firstValue = 0, int? secondValue = 0) { }
```

**Update:**

You have the ability to use anonymous types https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx within local scope to fix this issue if need. It's not the most elegant solution as these types can be difficult to work with, but you may find it feasible:

```
    public static void SomeAlgorithm(int? parameterOne, int? parameterTwo)
    {
        var values = new { FirstParameter = parameterOne, SecondParameter = parameterTwo };

        foreach(PropertyInfo info in values.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if(info.GetValue(values) == null)
            {
                //Your code would go here.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: cool idea - thanks. Did not think of possibly packaging the whole set of input parameters to those functions in some wrapping object, as properties. I suppose there's no way to do something clever about plain local scope variables, or method parameters ?

Comment: Updated original response to accommodate for local variable iteration.